# How to get a call back on uninstalling android application from ones application

Tags: android

**Registering broad cast**

```
IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter();
        filter1.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
        filter1.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
        filter1.addDataScheme("package"); // add addDataScheme
        pkgRemoveReceiver=new ApplicationUninstallReceiver();
        registerReceiver(pkgRemoveReceiver, filter1);
```

**Permission in manifest**

```
<receiver android:name="com.pcclean.app.receivers.ApplicationUninstallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />

        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Broadcast receiver**

```
public class ApplicationUninstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I'm not getting any call in on receive method.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see much wrong with code. A minor point though. The manifest file is missing the `PACKAGE_REMOVED` filter. Inside `<intent-filter>` of receiver in manifest file, add

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
```

Dynamically registering a BroadcastReceiver will have the disadvantage that notification will be received only if your app is running ( or in background ). Since you have already added the receiver in your manifest, there is no need to register it dynamically again. Also a correction in terminology - `PACKAGE_ADDED` and `PACKAGE_REMOVED` are not permissions exactly. There is no special permission required to receive notification on app install/uninstall.

Of lesser importance - I hope you are not attempting to receive a notification on the removal of your application itself. You will **not** get a notification on install/removal of your application itself([1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)).